# Store formatted data

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to store formatted data using HTML5 and retreiving it with jQuery?

```
<li data-title="description here">My element</li>

$('li').data('title');
```

I'm talking about simple line breaks and bullets perhaps.

Comment: How the code above doesn't work for you? Seems correct to me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put anything inside an attribute, including HTML that can be used elsewhere - however keep in mind that the characters `<`, `>` and `"` should be escaped as `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;` respectively to ensure the parser doesn't have any troubles with it.

Comment: I tried &lt;li> but it just print out the code as text. Shall I do both brackets? I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any special characters inside it you would have to escape them using **backslash \**  or by using the unicode equivalent of that character